# sub query for counting the experience

Tags: mysql

Using a sub query, display names of all faculty members who were hired before Davis Carr and their years of service (rounded to 0 decimal places).

Here is my query:

```
Select CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) As 'Faculty Name' ,faculty.DateHired AS 'Years Of Services'
from faculty
where faculty.DateHired < (select faculty.DateHired from faculty where faculty.FacultyID = 1239)
```

i want to count the years of services but the output is being displayed date hired like (2000-08-22).

But i want to show the output similar to this one:

```
faculty name  | years of experience

Dean joans     19

sean ali       14
```

i don't know how to do this kindly please, help me where i am doing wrong. If you want to see any data you can see in the given screen shot. Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo9Oa.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sub query for counting the experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234793/sub-query-for-counting-the-experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concern is to get Years of Service.

you can do it by replacing faculty.DateHired AS 'Years Of Services' 
 To 
  FLOOR(datediff(current_date(),faculty.DateHired) / 365) as 'Years Of Services'
so entire statement will be like

Select CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) As 'Faculty Name' ,FLOOR(datediff(current_date(),faculty.DateHired) / 365) as 'Years Of Services'
from faculty
where faculty.DateHired < (select faculty.DateHired from faculty where faculty.FacultyID = 1239)

Comment: most welcome my pleasure.if you think answer helped you, please vote me.